# Running an Applet with html Having Mysql Connector

Tags: java, mysql, applet

Hi Guys I have This Applet that Displays with the Error as I have Posted Below. The Screen Shot of my build folder also is there Where Do I place the mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar file so that It can connect with My Applet from a Web Browser???

The Applet Runs well When I run it manually as the Mysql Jar is in the Class path.
[image: My Application from a web Browswe]

Here is My Build Directory:
[image: Build]

My Login.html File looks like this :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>MY Applet</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>



<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">My Applet<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="Login.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the applet element is:

```
<APPLET 
    codebase="classes" 
    code="Login" 
    archive="mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar"
    width=350 
    height=200>
</APPLET>
```

The archive would need to be located at:

```
classes/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
```

But Alex is right about the part that an applet should not have direct access to the DB.  The DB should be placed behind an interface (e.g. a web-app.) that hides the details of the server, authenticates users, and regulates user activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should never implement applet that uses database directly. Applet by definition runs in browser and should talk to server via HTTP only. You should implement server side component that exposes Web service API (soap, rest, whatever). The server side component should work with DB while applet should work with the API exposed by this component.

EDIT. 
You can however add mysql driver to the applet classpath. It will probably work for you while both DB and browser are running on the same machine but will fail for regular user that is typically behind firewall.

Comment: You are right About Placing it in Classes Directory but Why does it Not Connect to the DB? I get this error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server` The Applet connects when it it Run Independently Without the html page.